# How to Update a Label in Pyglet without Invalid Operation Error?

Tags: python, multithreading, pyglet

I have a pyglet program that runs a GUI in one thread and receives a message from another thread. It's supposed to update the GUI based on that message. The problem though is whenever I go to update a GUI element, I get an error message like this one:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File --- line 40, in run
    pub.sendMessage("update", msg="Banana")
  File --- line 77, in updateDisplay
    self.label.text = msg
  File "---\pyglet\text\__init__.py", line 289, in text
    self.document.text = text
  File "---\pyglet\text\document.py", line 294, in text
    self.insert_text(0, text)
  File "---\pyglet\text\document.py", line 425, in insert_text
    self.dispatch_event('on_insert_text', start, text)
  File "---\pyglet\event.py", line 408, in dispatch_event
    if handler(*args):
  File "---\pyglet\text\layout.py", line 1045, in on_insert_text
    self._init_document()
  File "---\pyglet\text\layout.py", line 1034, in _init_document
    self._update()
  File "---\pyglet\text\layout.py", line 957, in _update
    lines = self._get_lines()
  File "---\pyglet\text\layout.py", line 933, in _get_lines
    glyphs = self._get_glyphs()
  ...
  File "---\pyglet\font\base.py", line 246, in fit
    region.blit_into(image, 0, 0, 0)
  File "---\pyglet\image\__init__.py", line 1730, in blit_into
    self.owner.blit_into(source, x + self.x, y + self.y, z + self.z)
  File "---\pyglet\image\__init__.py", line 1622, in blit_into
    glBindTexture(self.target, self.id)
  File "---\pyglet\gl\lib.py", line 107, in errcheck
    raise GLException(msg)
pyglet.gl.lib.GLException: b'invalid operation'
```

The operative error being **pyglet.gl.lib.GLException: b'invalid operation'**

I know `self.label.text = Y` works because it updates the text if I put it in the `init()` function. However, trying to do any kind of update from the `update_display` function (see code below) throws this error. I know the function gets called correctly because it successfully prints the message to console, but it breaks on the update element line. I've tried other elements than label and it's the same thing.

I have no idea why it's throwing this error or how to resolve it. Any ideas?

My code is:

```
import pyglet
from threading import Thread
from random import choice
from time import sleep
from pubsub import pub

RUN = True


class MessageThread(Thread):

    def __init__(self):
        """Init Thread Class."""
        
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.start()    # start the thread

    def run(self):
        """Run Thread."""
        
        array = [0, 1, 2]
            
        while True:
    
            if RUN == False:
                print("End runner")
                break
            
            value = choice(array)
            sleep(1)
                
            if value == 0:
                print("event", value, ": Apple", flush=True)
                pub.sendMessage("update", msg="Apple")

            elif value == 1:
                print("event", value, ": Banana", flush=True)
                pub.sendMessage("update", msg="Banana")
                
            else:
                print("event", value, ": Carrot", flush=True)
                pub.sendMessage("update", msg="Carrot")

        
class MyGUI(pyglet.window.Window):
 
    # Note: With this structure, there is no "self.app", you just use
    # self. This structure allows onDraw() to be called.
    
    def __init__(self):
        
        super(MyGUI, self).__init__(width=600,height=650,resizable=True) 
        
        self.label = pyglet.text.Label('Waiting...',
                          font_name='Times New Roman',
                          font_size=36,
                          x=self.width/2, y=self.height - 36,
                          anchor_x='center', anchor_y='center')
        
        # create a pubsub receiver
        # update is the topic subscribed to, updateDisplay the callable
        pub.subscribe(self.updateDisplay, "update") 
        
        MessageThread()
        
    def on_draw(self):
        self.clear() 
        self.label.draw()     
            
    def updateDisplay(self, msg):
        """ Receives data from thread and updates the display """
        
        print ("Updating Display")
        self.label.text = msg
            
    def on_close(self):
        """ Override the normal onClose behavior so that we can 
            kill the MessageThread, too
        """
        print("Closing Application")
        global RUN 
        RUN = False
        self.close() # Need to include since defining on_close overrides it


if __name__ == "__main__":
    window = MyGUI()
    pyglet.app.run()
```

Comment: You're more or less not allowed to tinker between threads, that goes for any threaded application. But most importantly graphical threads. If you on the other hand, let the graphical thread fetch data from your MessageThread, and do graphical stuff - that will work :)

Comment: Shouldn't sending a message do the same thing though as fetching data? Since it's not directly tinkering?